# Different container height on Firefox, when child element has moved top outside container

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have container (overflow:hidden;) with child element witch have `height: 2000px; top: -1000px;`. In Chrome my basic container has 1000px height. I can see bottom part of child element and top 1000px part is hidden outside viewport. 
The problem is on Firefox. The top part of child element is hidden - just like on Chrome, but my basic container has 2000px height. 
Is there any trick I can use to FF container height is 1000pz like in Chrome?

EDIT: 1000px and 2000px is example height - the real height of elementsare dynamic and depend on window.height.

Comment: You need to provide us with code for us to be able to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want different CSS for different Browsers, here is a useful bit of JavaScript that I use.
Since you have not provided any HTML, we wont be able to help you further as we can not see where the CSS could be affecting different browsers.

```
    function browserDetect (){
    var BrowserDetect = {
            init: function () {
                this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "Other";
                this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent) || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion) || "Unknown";
            },
            searchString: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var dataString = data[i].string;
                    this.versionSearchString = data[i].subString;

                    if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) !== -1) {
                        return data[i].identity;
                    }
                }
            },
            searchVersion: function (dataString) {
                var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
                if (index === -1) {
                    return;
                }

                var rv = dataString.indexOf("rv:");
                if (this.versionSearchString === "Trident" && rv !== -1) {
                    return parseFloat(dataString.substring(rv + 3));
                } else {
                    return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index + this.versionSearchString.length + 1));
                }
            },

            dataBrowser: [
                {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Chrome", identity: "chrome"},
                {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "MSIE", identity: "explorer"},
                {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Trident", identity: "explorer"},
                {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Firefox", identity: "firefox"},
                {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Safari", identity: "safari"},
                {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Opera", identity: "opera"}
            ]

        };

        BrowserDetect.init();
        //console.log("You are using " + BrowserDetect.browser + " with version " + BrowserDetect.version);     
        $('html').addClass("browser-"+BrowserDetect.browser);
        $('html').addClass("version-"+BrowserDetect.version);
};
```

By calling  browserDetect() on load, this will allow you to write custom CSS for any browser type or version.
Now all you need to do is add a class .browser-firefox before your CSS class and it will apply it for that browser.

Comment: Thanks for idea but this 1000px height of container is just a example. The container height is dynamic and its depend on window.height so adding specific class for FF it's not good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce your problem with the info you provided.

Maybe you can find some error on your CSS using this example?

Maybe you forgot to specify height of the outer box?

Using this HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">

    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.inner
{
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    top: -101px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff00ff;
}

.outer
{
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/dr7ztoz5/1/)

As you can see, the code is working like a charm - tested in my own Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari, Opera. :)

Comment: Check my Edit in first post - there is an answer for your question